# trim string in java, remove white space

Tags: java, jsp, trim

`<%=CMSStringUtility.toTitleCase(attrValues.getDisplayLabel())%>`

this returns a string with a leading white space character that I need to remove. I believe this is JAVA in a jsp file. I tried the following:

`<%=CMSStringUtility.toTitleCase(attrValues.getDisplayLabel()).trim()%>`

and

`<%=CMSStringUtility.toTitleCase(attrValues.getDisplayLabel().trim())%>`

I am a JSP newbie, any ideas?

Comment: Can you give a sample string?

Comment: The former version you tried should work.  Is it possible it isn't a whitespace but some other character?  Like a tab?

Comment: So what is your question?  Is the code above not working as expected?

Comment: @Gregg, a tab is a whitespace character.

Answer (score 6):

If `trim()` does not remove a whitespace, it means it is not in the predefined list of whitespaces. This is usually a non-breaking space (code 160). Try to iterate the `toCharArray()` and see the ascii code of the space.

Answer (score 0):

trim only removes leading and trailing spaces. To remove other invisible characters you may use a regular expression.