# how to completely clear an invisible string (pre fetch inputbox value) in jsp

Tags: javascript

[image]

though I set a 'required' with the input tag and also wrote a onclick form validation function for prevent an empty str ,yet its redirecting to the next page containing an empty string,afer that I found its taking some prefetch value which part can be selected.this invisible selected pre fetch value is redirecting to the next page as a string which.How to clear completely  this pre fetch value from input box when I will clear the textbox.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try a trim() on validade?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758407/5626568

Answer (score 0):

You will want to trim the value of all white space. You have not provided any code, so I have used the var docName as the form field that you are attempting to validate. There are a number of methods to find a null value, but this is the answer in its simplest form.

```
if (docName.trim() != '') {
    form.submit();
}
```

Comment: if (frm.name1.trim() != '') {
     frm.submit();
      }  here frm is my form name, doctr input box name- name1